# What does the letter c do in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While using Snowflake, I saw the letter c within a WHERE clause

`WHERE unnest_channel IN ('Referral - Merchant','Referral - Whitelabel')c`

What does it do? (Some kind of casting?)

Comment: Are you sure that is valid SQL? looks like it would produce an error to me.

Comment: Was it part of a sub-select which could indicate an alias?

Comment: Do you have an exemple query using it ?

Answer (score 0):

The default string is simply c, which specifies:

Case-sensitive matching.

Single-line mode.

No sub-match extraction, except for REGEXP_REPLACE, which always uses sub-match extraction.

POSIX wildcard character . does not match \n newline characters.

When specifying multiple parameters, the string is entered with no spaces or delimiters. For example, ims specifies case-insensitive matching in multi-line mode with POSIX wildcard matching.

If both c and i are included in the parameters string, the one that occurs last in the string dictates whether the function performs case-sensitive or case-insensitive matching. For example, ci specifies case-sensitive matching because the “i” occurs last in the string.